# Remove emtpy dictionary values when dumping yaml

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, pyyaml

I'm creating a script that gets data from our CMDB and creates inventory for ansible. However when I'm creating emtpy dictionaries for hosts and dumping it to yaml using ruamel.yaml the file that is created puts an empty dictionary brackets for each host:

```
groups = {
            "all": 
                {
                "children": {      
                    "team_servers": {
                        "hosts": dict()
                        },
                    "tool_servers": {
                        "hosts": dict()
                        },
                    "ungrouped": { 
                        "hosts": ungrouped
                    }
                }
            }
        }

for p in partition:    
    if "tools" in p.name:
        if host.name not in groups["all"]["children"]["tool_servers"]:
           groups["all"]["children"]["tool_servers"]["hosts"][host.name] = dict()

def return_yaml(self):
    yml = yaml.YAML()
    yml.explicit_start = True
    data = json.loads(self.inventory, object_pairs_hook=yaml.comments.CommentedMap)
    yaml.scalarstring.walk_tree(data)
    yaml_inventory = yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=True)
    print(yml.dump(data, sys.stdout))
```

Output:

```
---
all:
  children:
    tool_servers:
      hosts:
        hostname1: {}
        hostname2: {}
        hostname3: {}
        hostname4: {}
```

Desired output:

```
all:
  children:
    tool_servers:
      hosts:
        hostname1:
        hostname2:
        hostname3:
        hostname4:
```

Comment: Don't assign dicts if you don't want dicts? `…[host.name] = ""` instead of `…[host.name] = dict()` would give you strings

Comment: The value associated with a hostname in an Ansible inventory **is** a dictionary, so the output produced by `yml.dump()` is perfectly correct. Do you want to remove the empty dictionaries simply for aesthetic reasons? Operationally the two inventories you show are completely equivalent.

Comment: ...but don't do what @flyx suggested, because setting the value of the host key to an empty string will produce an invalid inventory. Set it to `None` to produce the output you show in your second inventory example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the dictionary for testing

```yaml
  _all:
    children:
      tool_servers:
        hosts:
          hostname1: {k1: a, k2: b}
          hostname2: {}
          hostname3: {}
          hostname4: {}
```

---

Use Jinja to convert the values

```yaml
  _hosts: |
    {% for k,v in _all.children.tool_servers.hosts.items() %}
    {% if v|length > 0 %}
    {{ k }}: {{ v }}
    {% else %}
    {{ k }}:
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

and create the dictonary

```yaml
  _out:
    children:
      tool_servers:
        hosts: "{{ _hosts|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _out:
    children:
      tool_servers:
        hosts:
          hostname1: {k1: a, k2: b}
          hostname2: null
          hostname3: null
          hostname4: null
```

Setting the empty value is the same as setting it to *None* or *null* which is the same. See below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          var1 type is {{ var1|type_debug }}: {{ var1 is none }}
          var2 type is {{ var2|type_debug }}: {{ var2 is none }}
      vars:
        var1:
        var2: null
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    var1 type is NoneType: True
    var2 type is NoneType: True
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    _all:
      children:
        tool_servers:
          hosts:
            hostname1: {k1: a, k2: b}
            hostname2: {}
            hostname3: {}
            hostname4: {}

    _hosts: |
      {% for k,v in _all.children.tool_servers.hosts.items() %}
      {% if v|length > 0 %}
      {{ k }}: {{ v }}
      {% else %}
      {{ k }}:
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

    _out:
      children:
        tool_servers:
          hosts: "{{ _hosts|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: _out|to_yaml
```